# Oracle SQL: Add sum from another table to query results

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables where one of the tables, TABLE2, has a column for TABLE1_IDs, thus there is a many-to-one relationship between TABLE2 and TABLE1 rows.  TABLE2 has a column PRICE which is a number that represents a dollar amount.  I have a query that obtains certain rows of TABLE1, but I want to get the total of all corresponding TABLE2 rows' PRICE values as an additional column in the query results.

How do I accomplish this in Oracle?

Comment: have you tried SQL? it is pretty cool :)

Comment: Yeah this should be pretty easy for someone who knows SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want something like this:

```
SELECT A.Id, SUM(B.Price) TotalPrice
FROM (  SELECT *
        FROM Table1
        WHERE Something) A
LEFT JOIN Table2 B
ON A.Id = B.Table1_id
GROUP BY A.Id
```

Answer (score 4):

Easy - join, and sum.

```
select t1.table1_id
,      sum(t2.price) total_price
from   table1 t1
,      table2 t2
where  t1.table1_id = t2.table1_id
group  by t1.table1_id;
```